# Ubuntu: use crontab file from another directory

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to deploy crontab file with my code. So use smth like `/home/crontab` file.

It's not very convenient for me to edit /etc/crontab file or use crontab -e on server.

**Is that possible?**

As I unserstood, symlink will crash everything.
I haven't found the solution in both popular questions: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515341/how-to-delegate-within-a-crontab-to-use-another-file-as-a-crontab-aka-crontab-i), [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54857/can-symlinks-be-used-in-etc-cron-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. crontab -l > my-crontab
2. crontab my-crontab

give it a look for this answer also:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/216692/where-is-the-user-crontab-stored